# How to Implement on scroll load ListView in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter, onscrolllistener

I have implemented listview in fragment. In that listview i have used custom adapter to display images with their description. Data is coming from web server. There are many list items with image so I'd like to implement on scroll load ListView for the same.

Which approach should i follow to do the same? I have tried to google it and found some sample but it does not fit into my requirement.

Here is the code of my Fragment containing listview. Thanks in advance.

> FragmentTab1.class

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends Fragment implements
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

DisplayImageOptions options;
protected ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
JSONArray AdsArray = null;

String TAG_IMAGE = "image";
String TAG_DISCRIPTION = "description";
ListView lv;
final Context context = getActivity();

static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> adList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container,false);

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showStubImage(R.drawable.no_image).cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc()
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();

    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    adList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    new LoadMyAds().execute();
    return rootView;
}


class LoadMyAds extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        String type = "all";
        JSONObject json = userFunction.myAds(userid, type);
        try {
            if (json.getString("status") != null) {
                String res = json.getString("status");
                if (Integer.parseInt(res) == 1) {
                    adList.clear();
                    AdsArray = json.getJSONArray("myadslistsArray");
                    for (int i = 0; i < AdsArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = AdsArray.getJSONObject(i);                           
                        String description = c.getString(TAG_DISCRIPTION);                          
                        String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();                            
                        map.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);                          
                        map.put(TAG_DISCRIPTION, description);                      adList.add(0, map);
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "parsing error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // image parameter need to be added

        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(adList));
    }
}

class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> locallist;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        locallist = list;
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration
                .createDefault(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return locallist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return null;
        return getItem(getCount() - position - 1);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row = convertView;


        if (row == null) {
            row = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.ad_list_item, null);

            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.desc= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);                           
            viewHolder.img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);

            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();

        holder.desc.setText(""+locallist.get(position).get(TAG_DISCRIPTION));

        imageLoader.displayImage(locallist.get(position).get(TAG_IMAGE),
                holder.img, options);
        return row;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView desc;
    protected ImageView img;
}
}
```

Comment: use a SimpleCursorAdapter with a "lazy" Cursor that loads its data on demand: see AbstractWindowedCursor

Comment: @Niraj Patel

Use paging to fetch data from API.
Like get 10 or 20 records at once and when user scrolls bottom of list call web service to fetch next set of records.

Answer (score 0):

Attach scroll listener to the listView

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());
```

Here is the class implementation:

```
  class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

         new LoadMyAds().execute();

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any sample or example which uses above method?